# Data Leak Prevention software for mac OSX

Tags: software-recommendation, security, encryption

We are using a software in window environment which provides the following feature to prevent a data leak. This software is protecting a folder which contains a lot of AI and PS file in window enviroment.

This software protect the file in the following way:

1. Passive encryption when file is saved so the file can't be opened in other computer if the whole harddisk is stolen.
2. Prevent unauthorized USB access the file is prohibited to copy to any external storage.
3. Limit the file access only in intranet, if the computer can't connect to intranet the file can't be opened.

In window, the software is based on **[Minifilter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg462968)** which is a **Microsoft** Technology

Can someone suggest a similar Data Leak Prevention software for mac OSX?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't really describe how your software works, but if you work with an app like [Exces](http://excesapp.com/) (that make it easy to work with, but the feature is available to OS X without the software) you can always work on an encrypted image and close it after use.

Of course you can use [Filevault](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FileVault) as well to maintain your filesystem encrypted.

Sadly, these have nothing to do with number three, since that is network dependent.

Comment: Exces seems be acceptable although it is not a passive encryption but it will lock the file after 10 minute. Am I right? I would try to study the feasibiliy of Filevault, thx anyway.

Comment: Exces preference pane is very sparse, the only "option" you can see is Auto-lock vault when idle. What is "idle" for excess I am not sure. :) Do use FileVault to increase overall security. What OS X are you using?

Answer (score -2):

CoSoSys provide full Data Leakage Prevention software for mac OSX.

http://www.softek.co.uk/prod/co/dlp_data_leakage_for_mac_osx.asp

Comment: Thanks for the link. Do be sure to fill out your user profile so that people can see you are disclosing your relationship with the product. :-) http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/behavior should help towards the bottom. Also, could you flesh out the post to explain if your proposed solution addresses some or all of items 1, 2, and 3 listed in the question?